# Classification output from a neural network vs SVM

Tags: neural-networks, svm, softmax

I have a classification problem which i have run through both a neural network and an SVM. I am interested in the probabilities of all the different classifications rather than just assigning to correct class.

The neural network is using a Softmax output and the output probabilities are never very confident. My NN outputs rarely go about 50% while the SVM predicts up to about 90% which is more in line with what i expect for this problem. The NN predictions go in the correct direction but because i am interested in the probabilities rather than just the classification they don't appear to be accurate. I would like to try and improve the NN

A few ideas and thoughts i have tried

- Can i change the loss function cross entropy to decrease the loss in cases where the model is very long. I can't find any standard literature on this.
- Is softmax really a poor reflection of probability
- Is the NN underfitted? I don't believe so but are there easy ways to verify.
- Maybe the SVM is just better suited to this problem!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It seems like you might be interested in calibrating your outputs. I’m not sure that SVM would be the best tool for such a task. // What do you mean when you write those 50% and 90% figures? Are those your classification accuracy scores? Are they in-sample or out-of-sample?

Comment: How do you assess whether the probabilistic output is correct (i.e., calibrated)? Are you using a [proper scoring rule](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info) on a test/validation dataset?

Comment: Thanks for the information
I am not using the SVM to calibrate the output i am running a comparison between an SVM and a NN. The probabilities are the outputs of the classification problem produced by the two methods. Part of my problem is that i am running a classification when i am not interested in the end classification i am interested in the probabilities
The information on scoring is interesting i need to read further on that

I also got much better results switching out SGD optimizer for Adam. I thought SGD would get the best result but requiring more epochs.